# OrderList <p:ajax> Unable to attach behavior to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I got stuck with a problem which seems to have been solved here.
I want to use order list as it's in an example [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/orderList.xhtml).
But it doesn't work at all. I have nested `<p:ajax>` in order list like in an example.

Namely, I have got an error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: /resources/abc/rankingAnswer.xhtml @21,85`<p:ajax>` Unable to attach behavior to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent

My Primefaces config in pom.xml is

```
        <!-- prime faces -->
    <primefaces.version>5.1</primefaces.version>
    <primefaces.themes.version>1.0.10</primefaces.themes.version>
```

My view is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="question" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>

    <ui:decorate template="answerDecorator.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="component">
            <p:orderList value="#{cc.attrs.question.possibleAnswers}" var="answer" itemLabel="#{answer.text}" itemValue="#{answer}" controlsLocation="left" editable="true" >
                <f:facet name="caption">#{msg['survey.default.makeOrder']}</f:facet>
                <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{cc.attrs.question.onReorder}" />
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{answer.text}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:orderList>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:decorate>

</composite:implementation>

</html>
```

My model is

```
public class RankingQuestionDTO extends AbstractQuestionDTO implements Serializable {

    private ArrayList<RankingAnswerDTO> possibleAnswers;
    private boolean randomizeAnswers;
    private String text;

    public RankingQuestionDTO() {
        super(QuestionType.RANKING);
        this.text = MessageUtils.getBundle("survey.default.text");
        this.possibleAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
        this.possibleAnswers.add(new RankingAnswerDTO(MessageUtils.getBundle("survey.default.text")));
        this.possibleAnswers.add(new RankingAnswerDTO(MessageUtils.getBundle("survey.default.text")));
        this.randomizeAnswers = true;
    }

    public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        System.out.print(event.getObject().toString());
    }

    public void onUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
        System.out.print(event.getObject().toString());
    }

    public void onReorder() {

    }


    public void addEmptyPossibleAnswer()
    {
        this.possibleAnswers.add(new RankingAnswerDTO(MessageUtils.getBundle("survey.default.text")));
    }

    public ArrayList<RankingAnswerDTO> getPossibleAnswers() {
        return possibleAnswers;
    }


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setPossibleAnswers(ArrayList<RankingAnswerDTO> possibleAnswers) {
        this.possibleAnswers = possibleAnswers;
    }

    public void setRandomizeAnswers(boolean randomizeAnswers) {
        this.randomizeAnswers = randomizeAnswers;
    }

    public boolean getRandomizeAnswers() {
        return randomizeAnswers;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/orderList.xhtml) has the answer (emphasis mine):

> Pojo Support with Clip Effect, Captions, Custom Content, Reorder Controls and Events (**since v5.1.5**)

As does [issue 4501](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4501) (emphasis mine):

> Added
>
> - select
> - unselect
> - reorder
>
> **Target is 5.1.5 Elite and 5.2 Community**.

Comment: You beat me to it... was just started to edit myself... thanks (although the remark of searching upfront is kind of valid... Even the pf blog has an entry about it: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3356

Comment: This is not part of answer, but of comment. With 50+ reputation you can post comments on the question (although such a comment would be higly eligible for removal ... just flag/vote for close if you find that the question doesn't belong here).

Comment: Ok, making it part of a comment I can understand. And if it were removed after a certain period, I'd understand. But if it is directly removed, how to convey such things to the poster? Just downvoting (at 1000+ reputation) is weird. If there are flags for this then fine. Have to look those up then

Comment: Yep, it means that version 5.1.5 is only in Elite and Pro versions. That's a pity. The info on primefaces.org doesn't state about that (it's not for free yet). thanks.

Comment: You can always download the 5.1 source and the 5.2-SNAPSHOT, compare the java and js files for this component and 'backport'... Should not be that difficult. And what do you mean by 'The info on primefaces.org doesn't state about that...' No elite is not free (but it mentions that)